# With Bottle, how could I just peek the head of http request instead of receiving whole http request?

Tags: python, http, file-upload, bottle

I don't know if it is possible with Bottle. 
My website (powered by Bottle) allow users to upload image files. But I limited the size of it to 100K. I use the following code in web server to do that.

> ```
>     uploadLimit = 100 #  100k
>     uploadLimitInByte = uploadLimit* 2**10
>
>     print("before call request.headers.get('Content-Length')")
>     contentLen =  request.headers.get('Content-Length')
>
>     if contentLen:
>         contentLen = int(contentLen)
>         if contentLen > uploadLimitInByte:                
>             return HTTPResponse('upload limit is 100K')
> ```

But when I clicked upload button in web browser to upload a file with its size like 2MB, it seems the server is receiving the whole 2MB http request. 
I expect the above code just receive http headers instead of receiving whole http request. That could not prevent wasting time on receving unecessary bytes

Comment: Use the `head` method instead of `get`. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: Our website uses ckedtior to upload files. That js lib will send http post request if user click to upload files. It is out of my control.